# convert time to local time given city/state/country

Tags: php, function, datetime, timezone

I'd like to write a function that can convert a time in EST (USEast Standard Time) to a time in another local timezone.

The inputs will be "time in EST" in the form 'Y-m-d H:i:s' (i.e. 2011-08-23 05:05:35), "City" "State", and "Country"

The function should return the local time (i.e. if the city, state, country is San Francisco, California, USA, and time in EST is 2011-08-23 05:05:35, function should return 2011-08-23 02:05:35)

I tried to figure it out from php.net but it seems like I need a continent to specify a timezone...and I didn't know how to convert a country to a continent.

Thanks

Comment: http://www.geekality.net/2011/08/21/country-names-continent-names-and-iso-3166-codes-for-mysql/

Comment: Is "San Francisco, California, USA" freeform text input or some predefined value? Where does that come from and how many possible values are there?

Answer (score 18):

the PHP function `date_default_timezone_set('EST');` accepts timezone as EST or GMT maybe this can be a good alternative to your problem.

Answer (score 17):

I prefer:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
```